# Setting NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription value when using cordova-plugin-geolocation

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins

I'm building a mobile app using Cordova. I use `cordova-plugin-geolocation` to get the user's current location. To customize the location permission request on iOS it's needed to set the `NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription` plist value.

Generally, to set an iOS plist option it's needed to manually set the option value in the `platforms/ios/<app-name>/<app-name>-Info.plist`. The problem is that on each build the `cordova-plugin-geolocation` overwrites the custom value with it's default empty string.

A guess it has something to do with the following lines in the `plugins/cordova-plugin-geolocation/plugin.xml`:

```
<config-file target="*-Info.plist" parent="NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription">
  <string></string>
</config-file>
```

But if I try to set any value into that `<string>` it is not respected, because it seems that the `plugin.xml` is cached somewhere when the plugin is installed.

So any help with setting the `NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription` in a way that persists over project rebuilds is appreciated.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

NEW ANSWER:

If using Cordova CLI 6.5.0 or newer and latest version of `cordova-plugin-geolocation` (>=3.0.0), you should use `edit-config` tag in the `config.xml` like this:

```
<edit-config target="NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription" file="*-Info.plist" mode="merge">
    <string>your custom text here</string>
</edit-config>
```

OLD OUTDATED ANSWER:
Fork the github plugin

change the `NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription` with the text you want

```
<config-file target="*-Info.plist" parent="NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription">
    <string>your custom text here</string>
</config-file>
```

then remove the original geolocation plugin and install your fork with

```
cordova plugin add https://github.com/yourUsername/yourGeolocationFork.git
```

Comment: Thanks, that's what I was thinking about too. Not nice, but works.

Comment: how to do it for phonegap app?

Comment: @Jobayer I've updated my answer with the recommended way of doing it by now. Also applies to Phonegap

Comment: should I insert it after adding <plugin name="cordova-plugin-geolocation" spec="~3.0.0" /> in config.xml?

Comment: @Jobayer no, anywhere in the root of the config.xml or inside the iOS platform tag, but outside plugins as it will set the value even if you don’ Have the plugin installed

Comment: @jcesarmobile do we know what the mode="merge" is all about?

Comment: merge - Adds the specified attributes to the target element. Will replace the attribute values if the specified attributes already exist in the target element. https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/plugin_ref/spec.html#edit-config

Comment: putting anywhere in the root of the config.xml work for me

Answer (score 1):

A not yet released (to npm) version of the plugin supports this.

https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-geolocation/commit/f9f7a23c57daad5514ce3d830a2defeb93ba3f78

You can install it like this:

```
cordova plugin add https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-geolocation#f9f7a23c57daad5514ce3d830a2defeb93ba3f78 --save --variable GEOLOCATION_USAGE_DESCRIPTION="Your text here"
```

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer is not working for me with Phonegap build. The following works for me :

```
<gap:config-file overwrite="true" parent="NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription" platform="ios">
    <string> your custom text here</string>
</gap:config-file>
```