# Cordova Geolocation Plugin IOS 9.1 Authorization

Tags: ios, cordova, cordova-plugins

I'm developing a Cordova app for both Android and IOS. The base code is the same for both platforms; Android is woking fine, but IOS isn't. The popup that allows the user to grant access to geolocation isn't showing. My current setup is Cordova 5.4.0, Cordova-plugin-geolocation v1.0.1, IOS 9.1.

In my config.xml I've have this lines to setup the plugin:

```
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-geolocation" spec="^1.0.1" />

<gap:config-file platform="ios" parent="NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription" overwrite="true">
  <string>MESSAGE!</string>
</gap:config-file>
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: try adding source="npm" to the plugin tag

Comment: @jcesarmobile thanks for your comment but that doesn't make it work

Comment: probably the plugin is being installed after reading the <gap:config-file, and the NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription is created in plugin installation, so the key NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription doesn't exists and your message isn't applied. Best thing you can do is to fork the plugin and use your own message, see this related answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33637591/setting-nslocationwheninuseusagedescription-value-when-using-cordova-plugin-geol/33647501#33647501

Comment: [My code works on BOTH](https://github.com/jessemonroy650/Phonegap-GPS-Test)

Comment: The problem here isn't the code not working, it's the NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription message not being changed