# IOS PhoneGap app rejected by App store becasue of cordova-plugin-geolocation

Tags: ios, cordova, phonegap-plugins, cordova-plugins, phonegap-build

Apple App store has rejected my app & send this message **We noticed that your app requests the user’s consent to access the location but does not clarify the use of this feature in the permission modal alert.**

This app is developed using phonegap & we are accessing geolocation using a plugin named **cordova-plugin-geolocation**. They has also mentioned that apple can create problem & [suggest](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-geolocation#ios-quirks) to add following code

```
<edit-config target="NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription" file="*Info.plist" mode="merge">
     <string>need location access to find things nearby</string>
</edit-config>
```

I have added it like this & resubmit it again.

```
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-geolocation" spec="2.4.2" />
<edit-config target="NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription" file="*-Info.plist" mode="merge">
    <string>need location access to find things nearby</string>
</edit-config>
```

But they have sent same feedback. Now what should I do to fix this issue?

Comment: Do you also have the camera plugin installed? which geolocation plugin version are you using?

Comment: no about camera. plugin(cordova-plugin-geolocation) version is 2.4.2

Comment: What version of the PhoneGap CLI are you specifying in your config.xml? The syntax is different depending on the version, as described here: http://docs.phonegap.com/phonegap-build/configuring/config-file-element/d

Answer (score 2):

The problem is you are using an old version of the plugin that still uses variables for the usage descriptions, and the variables are overwriting the `edit-config` tag values with an empty value (the default one)

You have two options:

1. Update the geolocation plugin to 3.0.0 or greater and use the `edit-config` tag as you are doing now.
2. Set the usage description for Phonegap Build.

To set the usage descriptions for Phonegap Build you have to do it like this:

```
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-geolocation" spec="2.4.2">
   <param name="GEOLOCATION_USAGE_DESCRIPTION" value="I want to find stores nearby" />
</plugin>
```

This should work if you have `<preference name='phonegap-version' value='cli-7.0.1' />` or newer (or if you don't have any phonegap-version set as it will use the latest as default)

Answer (score 1):

Check in xcode projec generated by cordova if the `NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription` key really exists in Info.plist. Sometimes it happened that cordova build did not copy plugins config correctly and I had to write them by hand.

[image: How Info.plist should look like]

Comment: I have developed it using phonegap. How to check it from my phonegap account?

Comment: I thought you used phonegap offline. I don't think that you can access to xcode project in your account. 

Try this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33647501/1206360

Comment: Thanks. I have checked that link too. I am adding this plugin using above code in config.xml. I have not found any option to add this version from github repo as per their guideline.

Comment: This is phonegap, not cordova.

Comment: Phonegap and Cordova basically are the same thing.

Comment: Then how can i run it in phonegap ? cordova plugin add https://github.com/yourUsername/yourGeolocationFork.git

Comment: just wite phonegap plugin add https://github.com/yourUsername/yourGeolocationFork.git

Answer (score 1):

With PhoneGap Build this worked for me :

```
<gap:config-file overwrite="true" parent="NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription" platform="ios">
    <string>Your usage description</string>
</gap:config-file>
```

**Better Answer : Edit (20.04.2018)**

A much better solution is to use a more recent PhoneGap version in Build :

```
<preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="15" />
<preference name="phonegap-version" value="cli-7.1.0" />
```

Now the `<edit-config/>` tag will be recognized by Build.