# Cordova geolocation plugin issue on ios 11

Tags: iphone, cordova, geolocation, cordova-plugins, ios11

I installed the geolocation plugin in cordova

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-geolocation --variable GEOLOCATION_USAGE_DESCRIPTION="your usage message"
```

I noticed that with android it works well, but with ios no.
to solve the problem I inserted this rule into the info.plist.

```
<string>NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription</string>
<key>Test geo iphone</key>
```

After entering this rule the app finally asks me permission to detect the position.

**Why cordova does not automatically insert this rule in the info.plist file**?
Grazie Ciao!

Comment: Read my updated answer on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33637591/setting-nslocationwheninuseusagedescription-value-when-using-cordova-plugin-geol/33647501?noredirect=1#comment82415752_33647501. The core plugins no longer use the variables as they were colliding with other plugins, the recommended way of setting the usage description is to use `edit-config` tag (It's also explained on the plugin docs, in the quirks section)

Comment: 53/5000
So the edit-config should be inserted in the config.xml file?

Comment: Yes, going to edit the answer to make it clar